# PHP: cURL POST request right after cURL GET request

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a cURL POST request right after my first cURL request.
I'm new with PHP and server side.

My first request is a GET. With API response i'm doing a *if error -> curl_close* **or** *else -> new cURL POST request*. But the second request return nothing. I've tried with a "traditionnal Postman JSON request" and the request works, so the problem is from my PHP code.

```
/* First we try to have id user from his mail*/

$curl = curl_init();   
$usermail = "user@mail.com";

//url = url + email
$gen_url = "https://myendpoint.com/manage/v1/user?search_text=";
$url = $gen_url.$usermail;

//GET request return all info about user, we do this to have his userid 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $tokenDecode",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
));

$response2 = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  curl_close($curl);
} else {
  $userInfo = json_decode($response2, true);
  $userId = $userInfo["data"]["items"][0]["user_id"] . "<br>"; 

  /* We have the user_id, we can POST on user's additionnal fields */

  $gen_url2="https://myendpoint.com/manage/v1/user/";   
  $url2= $gen_url2.$userId;

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url2,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{'additional_fields':[{'id':98,'value':2}]",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Bearer $tokenDecode",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
    ),
  ));

  $response3 = curl_exec($curl);
  $err2 = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err2) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err2;
  } else {
    echo $response3; //Show nothing
  }
  }
```

My GET request work and i'm able to return what i want.
But it seems that my second cURL request is not send, it don't return any response.
Is the way i'm doing or thinking it is false? Or did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: The code as shown can not work, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{"additional_fields":[{"id":98,"value":2}]"` clearly is a syntax error.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(["additional_fields" => [ ["id":98,"value":2] ] ]),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case GET request is ok you can reset curl data via `curl_reset` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php) before setting data for POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by do initialization of cURL again for second request like below
`$curl2 = curl_init();` and use $curl2 in second request code

Answer (score 0):

Quotes on the POSTFIELDS line are confusing php, try this

```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{'additional_fields':[{'id':98,'value':2}]",
```

Comment: Thank you suspectus, I have modified it. It will be less confusing.
But the issue is still here.

Comment: Then you must have another issue. Try `php -l yourfile.php` - any errors?